# Creating an Index that is best for wildcard search through 40Million names

Tags: php, search, lucene, full-text-search, sphinx

**Task**: search for best matching results for a name-search with wildcard  inside a db with ~40Million names.  e.g. query='John' results might be 'John', 'Johnny', 'Smith John', 'ajohn'
**Candidates**: MySQL Full-text, Sphinx and Lucene.
**Observation**: I assume they all work with an inverted index, which might not be the best solution for such short "documents" (names), and a trie might be a lot more suitable.

Assuming this observation is correct, do these tools have configurations to be more suitable for my case? Are there other tools that can integrate easily in PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can only really speak for Sphinx. It does have a 'min_prefix_len' which specifically enables wildcard searches.

It has two modes,

1) Each prefix of a word is stored seperately (eg Johnny is stored with Johnny, Johnn, John, Joh, Jo, J) so each will match. REALLY FAST lookups, but at the expense of index size, and indexing speed.

and

2) the raw word is actully stored, and prefixes match against these. Much more compact indexes, and fast indexing. But search speed is not so good (sphinx has yet to implement optimization to - eg storing the word lists in trie. So a dedicated solution could well outperform sphinx in this mode.

Would suggest in mode 1, sphinx will perform your task amicably - and better than mysql. (but dont know how it compares to Lucene)

Comment: You said 'better than mysql', how much better? I assume building the index will make INSERTS work slower, how much compared to full text mysql index? And the SELECTS will be x times more?